# How to prevent push() to keep creating keys?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app that I need to upload a couple of images, all is working fine, the thing is this.

- If I reupload the same pictures they get replaced in the storage and just uploads the ones that are not there (this is fine and expected to work like this)
- Now, when that photos upload to the storage, it generates a download link for each one in the database, the thing is that when I reupload more files , it creates again all the download links for each image, what I want is just to keep adding the ones that are new and not reuploading all the same links with different keys

Here is an image of the problem:

[image]

The red box represents all the files I have in storage with each link, the below keys represent different links for the same files, so the problem is that is pushing every time different keys with links that are the same for the files, I want to keep only the links of that red square that are the first ones that create when the files are uploaded. I have this code to upload the links to the database

```
 File[] filesInFolder = folder.listFiles(); // This returns all the folders and files in your path
        for (File file : filesInFolder) { //For each of the entries do:
            if (!file.isDirectory()) { //check that it's not a dir
                result.add(new String(file.getName())); //push the filename as a string
                Log.e("Files",""+new String(file.getName()));


                    final StorageReference referenciaFotos  = mStorageRef.child("Archivos_Usuarios").child("Fotos").child(new String(file.getName()));

                    referenciaFotos.putFile(Uri.fromFile(file)).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                            String urlFoto = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();
                            Log.e("PhotoUrl",""+urlFoto);

                            String pushKey = mDatabase.push().getKey();

                            Log.e("pushKey",""+pushKey);
                            mDatabase.child("Usuarios").child(uid).child("URL_FotosUsuario").child(pushKey).setValue(urlFoto);

                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                            Toast.makeText(GaleriaGrupos2.this, "Can't Upload photos, try again later", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });

            }
        }
```

What I'm doing with this code is first list all the files from a folder, then upload each file and upload each download link to the database for that file, now when I launch again the method it will generate new random keys with the same links each time, but the files won't be replaced in the storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the `push()` method does, it generates random keys everytime is called and this is also what is happening in your code. It will not stop, unless you check if those particular files already exist in the database. For that I suggest you loop through all the childrens from your Firebase database and see if it exist and use `push()` method only if does not exist.

Comment: yes, the thing is that i need first to push() all the elements , and then check if they are there, i get what you are saying alex, thanks for your time !

Comment: You're welcome @GastónSaillén You're right, first check and push only if not exist.

Comment: yep, the thing is how i know that one of those images dont exists, because i have like 10 links with different keys, how programatically know when 1 file of those 10 is new

Comment: because if i use exists() method it will return true or false depending if there are childrens inside a key, but it will be always true

Comment: To check an image for existens you need to use a query. Because you already have the name of the files just query the database using: `equalTo(imageName)` method.

Comment: you mean query the names of the images in the storage?

Comment: Compare the name of the images that exist in Firebase Storage with the name exist in the Firebase database.

Comment: i think that i cant access to the name of the images in the firebase storage, i need to save the name of the images in upload time in the database, i will try to do a workaround, thanks alex !

Comment: That's right, this is what I'm talking about. You're welcome! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Every time you find yourself trying to check if a certain *value* already exists, consider using that value as a *key* instead. That's because unique *value* are hard to control in Firebase, but *keys* are automatically unique by definition.

Say you have these URLs:

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/z2a-emojichat.appspot.com/o/images%2F-KkRiyO2d5CGLgj17OHv?alt=media&token=ec9a3135-5552-44b6-a29d-63e92ecb5c1e
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/z2a-emojichat.appspot.com/o/images%2F-KkRjDAq7Wn-J7UHGqlg?alt=media&token=ab65d303-69ce-4689-b5dc-dcb00fb31ada
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/z2a-emojichat.appspot.com/o/images%2F-KkRj_tlL16qMDQSq3Uo?alt=media&token=e2d88eeb-85cb-4ef9-9e06-ee828eea8d20
```

If you store them with push IDs like you do now, you'll get a JSON object like this:

```
{
    "-L8A7CfqTeGu5O4ZZG-G": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/z2a-emojichat.appspot.com/o/images%2F-KkRiyO2d5CGLgj17OHv?alt=media&token=ec9a3135-5552-44b6-a29d-63e92ecb5c1e",
    "-KuOdWgSuZUpvfpj_4hJ": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/z2a-emojichat.appspot.com/o/images%2F-KkRjDAq7Wn-J7UHGqlg?alt=media&token=ab65d303-69ce-4689-b5dc-dcb00fb31ada",
    "-KkRiogHRn0MeItVNu2J": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/z2a-emojichat.appspot.com/o/images%2F-KkRj_tlL16qMDQSq3Uo?alt=media&token=e2d88eeb-85cb-4ef9-9e06-ee828eea8d20"
}
```

But let's see what happens when we instead base the key of the URLs themselves. A quick approach is to realize that most of the URL is going to be the same if you're only storing images in Cloud Storage for Firebase. So let's just use the unique bits of each download URL:

```
{
    "images%2F-KkRiyO2d5CGLgj17OHv?alt=media&token=ec9a3135-5552-44b6-a29d-63e92ecb5c1e": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/z2a-emojichat.appspot.com/o/images%2F-KkRiyO2d5CGLgj17OHv?alt=media&token=ec9a3135-5552-44b6-a29d-63e92ecb5c1e",
    "images%2F-KkRjDAq7Wn-J7UHGqlg?alt=media&token=ab65d303-69ce-4689-b5dc-dcb00fb31ada": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/z2a-emojichat.appspot.com/o/images%2F-KkRjDAq7Wn-J7UHGqlg?alt=media&token=ab65d303-69ce-4689-b5dc-dcb00fb31ada",
    "images%2F-KkRj_tlL16qMDQSq3Uo?alt=media&token=e2d88eeb-85cb-4ef9-9e06-ee828eea8d20": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/z2a-emojichat.appspot.com/o/images%2F-KkRj_tlL16qMDQSq3Uo?alt=media&token=e2d88eeb-85cb-4ef9-9e06-ee828eea8d20"
}
```

Now, since the key is based on the URL itself, if you ever try to add the same URL again, you're going to end up with the same key. And this you're by definition guaranteed that each URL is stored only once.